# Folder that automatically uploads to phone

Tags: sd-card, file-system, file-transfer

Here's something I that I want to do with my Android phone (Galaxy S2, CM9). I'll be happy if someone could tell me whether it's possible, and how.

I often want to transfer files from my computer to my phone. But it's a clunky process. the easiest way for me right now is to use AirDroid, but it's cumbersome. Connecting via usb is cumbersome too, because I need to enable the usb storage thing.

What I really want is this. I want a folder on my computer that I can put files into, and have them automatically uploaded to a dedicated folder on my phone's sd card without any further action on my part. It's important that this won't mean constantly having a heavy program working in the background on my phone, because it's slow enough as it is.

Any way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[FolderSync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite)** could come in handy here. Define a "folder pair" (i.e. which directory on your Android device to sync with which directory on your computer), using any of the available protocols (SFTP, Samba, or any other). Then either chose for some "auto-check" (e.g. have it synced every night), or push the button manually. Using the [paid version](http://www.appbrain.com/app/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full), you could even bring in [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker) – which is what I do: "Every night at 3am, when connected to any power source and to MY_WIFI network → Sync all my backups, photos, whatsnots" :)

Comment: I'd rather not have to wait until the night, I want it to happen immediately.

Comment: Ah, I see now there's a Sync button, so I'm good.

Answer (score 4):

One way you can achieve this is using an app - [rSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.kowalczuk.rsync4android&hl=en) and use a Tasker job to periodically (or conditionally) upload/download data from your phone. You can refer to rSync's documentation for its configuration and other setup steps. You can configure it to only specify required one way transfer of files.

Answer (score 1):

this feature (syncfolder pc to phone) will be developed in [SnapsBackups](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=it.android.nexusboys.pay.wifibck&hl=it) Android app. SnapsBackups execute backups phone to pc by wifi network and withtout human interaction. the backups will be performed when the system notifies the application that wifi network is connected. SnapsBackups evaluates that wifi is a personal wifi, verify that exist a backup for this network and execute it if necessary.

On a next release, SnapsBackups will allow to sync phone with folder pc. No background activity if not necessary.**Stay tuned!**

Comment: Nice to see this answer, since I've recently downloaded SnapsBackups and I like it. I hope to see this new feature soon, so +1 from me. (@user67521: I assume you're one of the devs...good luck with it!)

Answer (score 0):

I currently have a Moto G and I use Google Drive to transfer files to my device. If I want something to send a file right to my device without cables I use [Wifi File Transfer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.antosdr.wififiletransfer&hl=en). It's super lightweight and doesn't run in the background. It doesn't have a folder option but I like manually sending stuff right to my phone since I only have 8Gb of storage.

[note] The other answer from user67521 looks promising, I'll definitely check it out!